# Conditional statement as a conclusion

Tags: logic

What kind of argument (if it does count as an argument) would this be?

All men are mortal
Therefore, if Socrates is a man then Socrates is mortal

It's not a syllogism as far as I'm aware, so what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a syllogism "in disguise".

The "standard" form is :

> All men are mortal;
>
> Socrates is a man.
>
> > Therefore, Socrates is mortal.

If we consider its logical form, it is :

> **P,Q ⊨ R**

that is equivalent to :

> > **P ⊨ Q → R**.